# additional validations and exceptions with Passport in Nodejs and Express

Tags: exception, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I am using [passport-local-sequeliz](https://github.com/madhurjain/passport-local-sequelize)e to develop a personal project and I would like to incorporate personal exceptions and validations which must be passed before creating a new user.

the idea is to check the email feature which is not incorporated in contrast to username.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awesome [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) about local strategies. You may take a look at the repo as [well](https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/tree/local).

Take a look at [these lines](https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/blob/local/config/passport.js#L44-L53) configuring the email validation. There is a test made to check for duplicate registration based on emails. You can just extend this functionality to fit your needs